# WiFi Clients connected to same AP can't connect to each other

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, vlan, ubiquiti

I have a UniFi DreamMachine Pro in my home network.

One access point is connected to it directly via a ethernet cable.

Also I have split networks (VLANs) for my home devices, guests, IoT etc.

I currently have the issue that my HomeAssistant (Raspberry Pi, connected via WiFi) from time to time can't connect to other devices (Wireless) in the same VLAN when they are connected to the same AP.

I can ping the devices from the same AP on another device, while being in a different VLAN. I have also already tried to disable Client Device Isolation on the Wi-Fi network but unfortunately that didn't help.

Do you know how I can fix this issue so that the devices can communicate?

Comment: have you found any traces on why the pi failed to connect (name resolution, timeout, refused, etc)? what protocols are being used by your homeassistant? do they rely on multicast? is the pi configured to use a DNS server or are you using zero-conf networking protocols like mDNS (or are you connecting by IP)?

Comment: The Pi is trying to connect directly via IP address.
The Pi is connected via both, ethernet and WiFi but uses the WiFi interface for connecting to the IoT Devices. That is because some devices only respond to requests from the same VLAN as they are in. 

The Wired interface is in subnet 10.0.20.0/24 and the WiFi interface in 10.0.40.0/24.

I've uploaded the ouput of the ping commands here: [Imgur](https://imgur.com/a/Yqr3kN2)

Comment: "I can ping the devices from the same AP on another device, while being in a different VLAN.". So, since you have the vlans routing back and forth, why use a dual-homed configuration on the pi, instead of just using the wired connection? wifi is great and all, but I've never found it stable enough for infrastructure services like servers. its just too "twitchy".